# Where to install mingw-make from? (CMAKE)

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, mingw-w64, msys

I've been trying to compile my code with CMake using the "MSYS Makefiles" generator. I wrote the following command:
`cmake -S . -B build/ -G "MSYS Makefiles`
But I was presented with the following error:

```
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MSYS Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
    CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
    CMake Error: CMAKE_AR was not found, please set to archive program.
```

After some investigation, I found that I had to install something called "mingw-make" to do this. Apparently this "mingw-make" can be installed in the "MinGW gui". Note that I checked if I already have "mingw-make" installed and I don't.

I'm confused because I can't seem to find this "MinGW gui" anywhere. I installed MinGW, and only have an application on my computer called "Modify or Remove MinGW". I searched the install options, and couldn't find "mingw-make" anywhere.
Where can I download this "mingw-make" from? Thanks.

Comment: Uninstall your existing MinGW. Then install MSYS2. From there you can install both an up-to-date MinGW and mingw32-make.

Comment: Note that `mingw32-make` uses `MinGW Makefiles`, while `make` uses `MSYS Makefiles`. Both `mingw32-make` and `make` are available in MSYS2, and `make` is normally superior.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mingw32-make` only with `cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles"`.

Use `make` only with `cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles"`.

But if you want the best performance you should get [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) and use `ninja` with `cmake -G"Ninja"`.

MinGW is all command line, though there are some GUI installers for it. MinGW-w64 is the successor to MinGW which also supports 64-bit Windows.

There are standalone MinGW-w64 Windows releases available from https://winlibs.com/ that don't require installation steps, just extract. This also includes `mingw32-make`